Getting error as ORA-01821: date format not recognized in Oracle
I have a column in select statement where I am getting date like below
2017-12-21T12:00:44.064+05:30 and the column name is RFI_DATE but it's data type is NVARCHAR2.
but while I am selecting it like below
select sap_id, to_date(RFI_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_BIL;

I am getting error as

ORA-01821: date format not recognized


Have a look at your data. String '2017-12-21T12:00:44.064+05:30' does not match format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
DATE data type does not support fractional seconds nor time zones. If you like to use them, you must use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type. Would be this one:
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(RFI_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')


Thanks Wernfried, can it  further be converted to DD-MM-YYYY format for ?

The first step should be to convert the data type from VARCHAR2 to TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE or TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE - or maybe DATE or TIMESTAMP if you like to ignore fractional seconds and time zone. Then you can format to any output format using TO_CHAR

I want to get the No of Days by subtrating these 2 dates, but not able to do so. v_DURATION := NVL(ROUND((TO_DATE(SUBSTR(r.bill_end_date , 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(r.RFI_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') + 1)),0);

Operation with TIMESTAMP returns an INTERVAL. Either you extract the number of days from this interval or cast the TIMESTAMP into a DATE with CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(...) AS DATE) to get number of days as number. Better ask a new question for this, if you have problems.

yeah sure, will ask new question to resolve this as I have tried many times

You also have TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ supporting different variations of the ISO 8601 format:
select to_utc_timestamp_tz(replace('2017-12-21T12:00:44.064+05:30', '.', ',')) from dual ;
select to_utc_timestamp_tz(replace('2017-12-21T12:00:44.064+05', '.', ',')) from dual ;
select to_utc_timestamp_tz(replace('2017-12-21T12:00:44.064', '.', ',')) from dual;
select to_utc_timestamp_tz(replace('2017-12-21T12:00:44', '.', ',')) from dual;
select to_utc_timestamp_tz(replace('2017-12-21T12:00', '.', ',')) from dual;
select to_utc_timestamp_tz(replace('2017-12-21T12', '.', ',')) from dual;
select to_utc_timestamp_tz(replace('2017-12-21', '.', ',')) from dual;

Refer to the doc to understand which TZ is used when not specified in the parameter string.
NB
The replace '.' by ',' is due to a strange undocumented behavior (at least I didn't found any reference to that in the doc...) making TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ failing on some NLS_TERRITORY like France, Belgium, ... if the SEC to MILLISEC separator is a DOT (tested from 18c to 23ai).
It works with DOT on UNITED KINGDOM, AMERICA, CANADA, ...
and with COMMA it works on all available territories.

Yes, looks like Oracle still has to do some work on that. In contradiction to your case the documentation says "...specifies the seconds, as two decimal digits, 00 to 59, optionally followed by a decimal point" and "Unsupported dates and times include the following: 2018-10-26T21:32 (if a time is specified then all of its parts must be present)"

Short dates like to_utc_timestamp_tz('20241119') are also working. The documentation is a shame...
